# hex string with zeros left padded

Tags: java, formatting

To left pad a number with zeros if there are fewer than two digits we use this:

```
String.format("%02d", aBlkNo);
```

However, `aBlkNo` should be a hex string not a decimal. What can I do to render a two digit hex string from a `byte` with zeros padded when necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "x" or "X" instead of "d":

```
String.format("%02x", aBlkNo);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can simply add "padStart" to a string/hexString

```
val paddedValue = "a".padStart(2, '0')
println(paddedValue) // "0a"
```